# How can I access target name in a Parcel plugin?

Tags: javascript, target, parceljs

I'm using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) for a web extension project. I've defined 2 targets in `package.json` file:

```json
"targets": {
    "firefox": {
        "engines": {
            "browsers": [
                "last 1 Firefox version"
            ]
        }
    },
    "chrome": {
        "engines": {
            "browsers": [
                "last 1 Chrome version"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a transformer (or any plugin which does the trick) to combine a `manifest.json` and `manifest.{targetName}.json` before collecting manifest dependencies.

So far I have learned that `asset.env` gives some info about the current environment. But I'm looking for a way to get the target name. Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've come up so far is to use a custom *resolver*. A resolver has a `resolve` method. One of the arguments this method accepts, is `dependency` which has a nullable field `target`. This is what I was looking for.

Then for the combining of main manifest and target-specific manifest files, I can return the JSON content of merged files inside the `code` field of the function output.

This works fine in the build time. But still not working when I update manifest while `parcel watch` is running.